# How to fix "invalid type (NULL) for variable" error in ctree function using the party package in R?

Tags: r, syntax, decision-tree, party

I am using the `ctree()` in the party package from R. I want to be able to columns from more than one dataframe, for which I would call use column separately (using `$`) as I have in the past with this function but this time it is not working.

For the purposes of illustrating the error, I've put together a sample data set as a single dataframe. When I run:

```
>ctree(data$adult_age~data$child_age+data$freq)
```

I get the following error:

```
>Error in model.frame.default(formula = ~data$adult_age, data = list(),  : 
  invalid type (NULL) for variable 'data$adult_age'
```

If I run it like this, it works:

```
>ctree(adult_age~child_age+freq, data)
```

Usually those two ways of writing it out are interchangeable (e.g. with `lm()` I get the same results with both), but with `ctree()` I am running into an error. Why? How can I fix this so that I can pull from different dataframes at once without combining them?

My data structure looks like this:

```
> dput(data)

>structure(list(adult_age = c(38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 55.5, 55.5, 38, 38, 38), child_age = c(8, 8, 13, 3.5, 3.5, 13, 8, 8, 8, 13), freq = c(0.1, 12, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1, 2, 0.1, 0.1)), .Names = c("adult_age", "child_age", "freq"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 18L, 20L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L))
```

If you want to run the sample data:

```
>adult_age = c(38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 55.5, 55.5, 38, 38, 38)

>child_age = c(8, 8, 13, 3.5, 3.5, 13, 8, 8, 8, 13)

>freq = c(0.1, 12, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1, 2, 0.1, 0.1)

>data=as.data.frame(cbind(adult_age, child_age, freq))
```

Comment: Just don't. Relying on scoping is bad practice and can lead to strange errors. Most package devs assume that you use the `data` argument. Combine your data.frames (that should be very simple).

Comment: Why is it "bad practice"? I have called with `$` for years with `lm` and other functions for years without any issues. I run into problems when try to use the syntax where there are commas between column names and dataframe name.

Answer (score 3):

#### Why this approach should not be applied

*Never* use `data$` inside model formulas (as already pointed out by @Roland). Apart from the fact that you unnecessarily repeat the data name and have to type more, it is a source of confusion and errors. If you haven't encountered this problem, yet, with `lm()` then you haven't used `predict()`. Consider a simple linear regression for your `data`:

```
m1 <- lm(adult_age ~ child_age, data = data)
m2 <- lm(data$adult_age ~ data$child_age)
coef(m1) - coef(m2)
## (Intercept)   child_age 
##           0           0
```

Thus, both approaches lead to the same coefficient estimates etc. But in all situations where you want to use the same formula with a different/updated/subsetted data, you run into trouble. Prominently, in `predict()`, e.g., when making a prediction at `child_age = 0`. The intended usage with formula and data separated correctly recovers the intercept:

```
predict(m1, newdata = data.frame(child_age = 0))
##        1 
## 36.38919 
coef(m1)[1]
## (Intercept) 
##    36.38919
```

But for the `data$` version the `newdata` is not used at all in the actual prediction:

```
predict(m2, newdata = data.frame(child_age = 0))
##        1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8 
## 41.14343 41.14343 44.11483 38.46917 38.46917 44.11483 41.14343 41.14343 
##        9       10 
## 41.14343 44.11483 
## Warning message:
## 'newdata' had 1 row but variables found have 10 rows
```

There are more examples like this. But this one should be serious enough to refrain from this.

#### How it can be applied to `ctree()`

If you are determined to shoot yourself in the foot with the `data$` approach, you can do so with the new (and recommended) implementation of `ctree()` in the `partykit` package. The whole formula/data handling was rewritten, using standard nonstandard evaluation.

```
library("partykit")
ctree(adult_age ~ child_age + freq, data = data)
## Model formula:
## adult_age ~ child_age + freq
## 
## Fitted party:
## [1] root: 41.500 (n = 10, err = 490.0) 
## 
## Number of inner nodes:    0
## Number of terminal nodes: 1
ctree(data$adult_age ~ data$child_age + data$freq)
## Model formula:
## data$adult_age ~ data$child_age + data$freq
## 
## Fitted party:
## [1] root: 41.500 (n = 10, err = 490.0) 
## 
## Number of inner nodes:    0
## Number of terminal nodes: 1
```

Comment: I so love the phrase "standard nonstandard evaluation". :)

Comment: I hoped you might :-)